# Questions about induction and Big O

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, induction, asymptotics

Statement:

> For any $k \in \mathbb N$, the value of $\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^ni^k}$ is a polynomial in $n$ with the leading term $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{k+1}n^{k+1}}$ and next term $\displaystyle{\frac 12n^k}$.

Proof:

> By remark $(--)$, there's a polynomial $g$ s.t. $\displaystyle{k!\binom ik = i^k - \binom k2i^{k-1} + g(i)}$ with $g$ of degree at most $k - 2$ meaning $i^k = \displaystyle{k!\binom ik  + \binom k2i^{k-1} - g(i)}$.
>
> Let $k = 1$. The sum of first $n$ naturals is $\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^ni = \frac 12n^2 + \frac 12n}$ and so the claim holds for base case.
>
> For $k > 1$, we have $\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^ni^k = k!\sum_{i=1}^k\binom ik  + \binom k2\sum_{i=1}^ki^{k-1} - \sum_{i=1}^kg(i)}$.
>
> Now, $\displaystyle{ k!\sum_{i=1}^k\binom ik = k!\binom{n+1}{k+1}}$ by Hockey Stick identity and $\displaystyle{\binom k2\sum_{i=1}^ki^{k-1} = \binom k2\frac1kn^k + O(n^{k-1})}$ by induction hypothesis. Further note, $\displaystyle{\binom{n+1}{k+1} = \frac{n+1}{k+1}\binom nk}$.
>
> Thus we have $\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^ni^k = \frac{1}{k+1}n^{k+1} + \frac 12n^k + O(n^{k-1})}$.

My questions:

1. At the beginning of the proof $g$ is said to be $O(n^{k-2})$, but in conclusion of the proof $g$ is $O(n^{k-1})$. Is it by hypothesis? What I mean is if $g$ is of degree $k - 2$, then by hypothesis $g$ is $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{(k - 2)+1}n^{(k-2)+1} + O(n^{k-3}) = \frac{1}{k - 1}n^{k-1} + O(n^{k-3}) = O(n^{k-1})}$. Does that make sense? If not, what's the reason for this?
2. I am not sure we showed the step from $k$ to $k+1$ holds in the proof. Is it done implicitly? Can someone, please, point out where in the proof the step $k \implies k+1$ happens? Thanks.

Comment: The polynomial depends on $k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $g$ is a polynomial
of degree at most
$k-2$, then
$|g(n)|
\le cn^{k-2}$
for some $c$
for large enough $n > n(c)$,
so
$g(n) = O(n^{k-2})$
and

$\begin{array}\\
|\sum_{i=1}^n g(i)|
&\le |\sum_{i=1}^{n(c)} g(i)|+|\sum_{i=n(c)+1}^n g(i)|\\
&\le n(c)\max_{i=1}^{n(c)}|g(i)|+|\sum_{i=n(c)+1}^n ci^{k-2}|\\
&\le n(c)\max_{i=1}^{n(c)}|g(i)|+|\sum_{i=n(c)+1}^n cn^{k-2}|\\
&\le n(c)\max_{i=1}^{n(c)}|g(i)|+cn^{k-1}\\
\text{so}\\
\dfrac{|\sum_{i=1}^n g(i)|}{n^{k-1}}
&\le \dfrac{n(c)\max_{i=1}^{n(c)}|g(i)|+cn^{k-1}}{n^{k-1}}\\
&= c+\dfrac{n(c)\max_{i=1}^{n(c)}|g(i)|}{n^{k-1}}\\
&\le c+1\\
\end{array}
$

for
$\dfrac{n(c)\max_{i=1}^{n(c)}|g(i)|}{n^{k-1}}
\lt 1$
or
$n
\ge (n(c)\max_{i=1}^{n(c)}|g(i)|)^{1/(k-1)}
$.

Therefore
$\sum_{i=1}^n g(i)
=O(n^{k-1})$.